# What is the measure of decoherence?

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

Assume we have a qubit, and it is interacting with the environment.
I know that people say that when the qubit is in
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
It is fully coherent. But when it evolves
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0&\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
It is said that the system is fully decohered. I wonder what is the measure of the degree of decoherence? Is von Neumann entropy a measure of the decoherence?

Comment: These are density matrices, I suppose?

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, these are density matrix

Comment: I think you're confusing "decoherence", as a process, and "purity", which is a property of the state. "Decoherence" refers to a class of processes that generally lead to increasing the mixedness (reducing the purity) of a state, thus making it lose its "quantum properties"

Answer (score 0):

In time domain decoherence is usually characterized by the rate of decay of *coherences*, i.e., the non-diagonal density matrix elements. This, of course, is dependent on the mechanism that causes decoherence. Note that a qubit can be described in terms of [Bloch equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_equations), in which case time $T_2$ is referred to as decoherence time.

However, what the question seems to asking is the measure of the [purity of the state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)) (i.e., whether it is a coherent superposition or not), for which a basis-independent measure is
$$
\gamma=tr(\rho^2)
$$
A pure, i.e., completely coherent state, has purity $\gamma=1$, as can be checked with the matrix given in the OP.

Comment: I am asking the decoherence. So the measure of the decoherence is the absolute value of the off diagonal element? The smaller it is, the larger the degree of decoherence?

Comment: @TanTixuan I am not sure that you correctly using this term: *decoherence* is a process (not a quantity), it is measured by a decoherence rate, how fast a pure state transforms into a mixed state.

Comment: @TanTixuan small non-diagonal elements by themselves do not mean decoherence - one can always transform a coherent density matrix to a diagonal basis.

Comment: Given your usage of the term, then it seems to me that we can use the Neumann entropy to measure whether a density matrix is decohered or not. Since it is independent of the basis and extremized for a pure density matrix

Comment: @TanTixuan Yes, indeed, von Neumann entropy is a good measure as well. [Here is a useful answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/500132/247642) about the relation between $\rho^2$ and the von Neumann entropy.